# comparing classes with webpack2 and react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

Before I upgraded to webpack 2, i could do the following:

```
   children: PropTypes.arrayOf((propValue, key) => {
      const type = propValue[key].type
      if (type !== Column && type !== ColumnGroup) {
        throw new Error('<Table> can only have <Column> and <ColumnGroup> as children.')
      }
    })
```

This no longer seems to work using webpack 2. The error always gets thrown. What is the proper way to compare react classes using webpack 2?

This is my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

UPDATE:

It has something to do with setting the NODE_ENV equal to something other than production. I'm able to reproduce this here: https://github.com/dadamssg/react-class-bug/tree/master

Comment: Are you using a minifier of some kind?

Comment: no. I'm using the CommonsChunkPlugin though. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: I don't think so. Which version of React are you using?

Comment: I have "^15.3.1" for react and react-dom and did an npm cache clean and install so whatever the latest is for that.

Comment: i've gotten closer to figuring it out. If I do not explicitly set the NODE_ENV when building, the problem goes away. Not really sure where to go from here though.

Comment: Previously, what was the value of 'NODE_ENV'?

Comment: i've edited the post with a link to a repo that illustrates the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is known issue caused by react hot loader.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9652

I worked around it by adding my own static variable on the component classes and comparing that.

```
   children: PropTypes.arrayOf((propValue, key) => {
      const {_componentClass} = propValue[key].type
      if (_componentClass !== Column._componentClass && _componentClass !== ColumnGroup._componentClass) {
        throw new Error('<Table> can only have <Column> and <ColumnGroup> as children.')
      }
    })
```

Not ideal, but it works.